# how to get an objects position in another object's coordinate system THREE.js

Tags: coordinates, three.js, webgl

I have created a THREE.Scene, and within the scene there is an THREE.Object3D() that is a new 'coordinate system'. 
Inside this object there is a particle with a certain position.
I understand that getting a this particle's position from the object's 'coordinate System' into the Scene's 'coordinate systems' requires the following

```
//Gives particle position in scene coordinates
particle.position.applyMatrix4(Object.matrixWorld)
```

What would be the inverse transformation though?

(aka, the particle is in the Scene's 'coordinate system' and I want to find its position in the objects 'coordinate system')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inverse transformation of the transform you referred to can be calculated like so:

```
var mInverse = new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse( object.matrixWorld );
particle.position.applyMatrix4( mInverse );
```

three.js r.55

Comment: How do you always know the answer to everything! also Thanks :)